# Using <xsl:for-each> for incremental element names

Tags: xslt, xpath, foreach, xslt-1.0

I have an XML that is converted from a java map. So all the map keys are converted into node names. The XML structure is as below

```
<map>
    <firstName>AAA</firstName>
    <firstName1>BBB</firstName1>
    <firstName2>CCC</firstName2>
    <firstName3>DDD</firstName3>
</map>
```

I am trying to write a for-each loop to extract data from this XML to create an output XML. I have tried most of the options available such as name(), local-name(), contains(), etc but couldn't come up with something that worked. What are the options available since the incremental node name can go upto count 100 or more. Any inputs in coding the  loop would be of great help. I am using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: What are you trying to get name(), etc. to do? Maybe if you show the desired output, we can help you produce it.

Comment: Also if you show the XSLT you've tried, it will help us understand what your intentions are and how to help you get there.

Comment: The answer did resolve the issue for looping. How do I now extract the values from firstName, firstName1, etc inside the for-each loop. My output will be something like repeated nodes for <partyFirstName>AAA</partyFirstName> <partyFirstName>BBB</partyFirstName> inside individual <party> nodes

Comment: See @RRitter's answer, specifically, `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`. If your for-each select is `"/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'firstName')]"`, then inside the for-each, the context node will be each element whose name starts with `firstName`.  `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` will output the string value (i.e. the concatenated text content of all descendants) of the context node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are many ways to select the children of the top element (`map`):**

```
/*/*
```

**This selects all elements that are children of the top element of the XML document.**

```
/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'firstName')]
```

**This selects all top element's children-elements, whose name starts with the string `'firstName'`.**

```
/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'firstName') 
   and floor(substring-after(name(), 'firstName')) = substring-after(name(), 'firstName')) ]
```

**This selects all top element's children-elements, whose name starts with the string `'firstName'` and the remaining substring after this is an integer.**

```
/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'firstName') 
   and translate(name(), '0123456789', '') = 'firstName')) ]
```

**This selects all top element's children-elements, whose name starts with the string `'firstName'` and the remaining substring after this contains only digits.**

**Finally, in XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) one can use regular expressions**:

```
/*/*[matches(name(), '^firstName\d+$')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The /*/*[starts-with(name(), 'firstName')] did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This will select all the first level elements and their information, which you can then use as you wish:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```